# ffmpeg.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, windows-server-2008, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I know there's a lot of "Entry point not found" posts; But i find that they don't fit on my problem.

When i try to run ffmpeg i get this error message:

[image: Entry point not found]

but the catch is that i only get the message is i run ffmpeg from my server application or from the folder where the server application is located `e:\StreamServer2\`
If i run from an other folder eg. `e:\StreamServer2.BAK\` there are no problem.
the same goes for when i run the StreamServer located in `StreamServer2.BAK`

The `ffmpeg.exe` is a copy of the same file.

I have tried to delete ffmpeg.exe and copy a new to the folder. As i assumed that it was ffmpeg.exe that was damaged when we moved the server to our new data center. but that did not make any difference.

I am running ffmpeg with thise parameters:

`ffmpeg.exe -analyzeduration 0 -fpsprobesize 0 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://addrOnIpCam -g 52 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -b:v 64k -q 5 test.avi`

and from server application:

`ffmpeg.exe -analyzeduration 0 -fpsprobesize 0 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://addrOnIpCam -g 52 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -b:v 64k -q 5 -an -`

Comment: You say windows-server-2008.  Do you know that this function only exists on Windows Server 2008 R2 and later?

Comment: No i did nor know thay, but it appears not to be true since it works from another folder and ffmpeg is the same build and file.